# Why is my .trash folder not visible in single user mode?

Tags: high-sierra, single-user

So I booted of to single user mode for fun and I was checking whether my trash folder will be present there but it was not and I also mounted / as read and write but when I boot to my Mac and then use terminal I can see my trash with its contents fine. I am just wondering why I can't access my trash in single user mode?

I actually checked if my trash folder exists by typing `ls -a /Users/homedirectoryname/`

Comment: Did you boot into single user or into recovery mode?

Comment: When you booted into Single User mode, did you mount the file system?

Comment: @Allan Yes I mounted the file system as read and write.